# Redirect page with value using ajax Jquery and asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I do have two page. One is Default.aspx and another one is DetailView.aspx. What I want to do is that I want to redirect page from Default.aspx to detailView.aspx using ajax call and I want to pass one value also. I have done something but it is not calling function that is defined into class.

I am calling this function from Default.aspx webfile

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
                url: 'DetailView.aspx/Test',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: '{pid:' + result + '}',
                success: function (data) {

                }
            });
```

this is class file of DetailView.aspx

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static string Test(string pid)
{
    return " ";
}
```

I was debugging this function but it is not calling this function at all when ajax being called.

Comment: you should also have an error block in your ajax call to see what the error is. That should give you an idea about whats missing.

Answer (score 1):

You want to convert a JavaScript value to a JSON using [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) before posting data.

### Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="DemoWebForm.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <button type="button" onclick="ajaxPostData();">Post Data to Detail View</button>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ajaxPostData() {
                var data = { pid: "One" };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/DetailView.aspx/Test") %>',
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        console.log(msg.d);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### DetailView.aspx.cs

```
using System.Web.Services;

namespace DemoWebForm
{
    public partial class DetailView : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public static string Test(string pid)
        {
            return "Hello " + pid;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: data: "{ \"rID\": \"" + result + "\" }"

Comment: data should be on this format 
data: "{ \"rID\": \"" + result + "\" }"

Comment: You do not need to place quotes. `data: {id: result };` should work *(assuming result is a variable name)* or post sample string first `data: {id: "test" };`  for testing. ***FYI***: If you rename property from ***pid*** to to ***id***, you will also have to rename parameter name to ***id*** in Test method.

Answer (score 1):

From your ajax Method Declaration i.e

1. URl Part in your Ajax Calling this one :

   `url: 'DetailView.aspx/Test'`

I'm assuming that Your are Using the `FriendlyURL` .

So in your `RouteConfig.cs`  please comment this line

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
```

2. You can send params to your Ajax as follows

   `var params = "{'pid:' " + result + "}";`

Replace that variable in your `AJax` calling as follows

```
   data: params
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have enabled ajax call in the webservice, to do so add this line before defining the webservice class

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()]
```